# the page is loades again when the links of menu is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I click on the link from the menu, the page is loaded a second time. so when I click on the menu the link is not active.

In the first visual I see that the menu is selected when I debug it. but when the code block is finished the page is loading a second time, so it removing the menu selection What should I do so that the page will not load again.

[Screen shot of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSQYW.jpg)

again After the page is loaded, first the inbound li is happening

[After clicking it reloads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kCGq.jpg)

I wanted to say in the pictures, but I wrote a code like this.

I wrote this code under $ (document) .ready

```
 $(".sidebar .nav li").on("click", function () {
    //$(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
    $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: You should post some code, otherwise how can we know what's wrong?

Comment: ok?I wanted to say in the pictures, but I wrote a code like this. ty.

Comment: It's not clear from your code, but are your `li`s wrapped in `a`s? Because in that case you should prevent the `click` event for the `a`s to fire.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably clicking on an `<a>` tag which will direct you to the specified URL. You can use JavaScript to prevent the click event from going to the URL of the `<a>` tag, by using something like this:

```
$(The selector on your <a> tag).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: thanks. I edited the code like this;

$(".sidebar .nav li a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});

but when I select a previous one the two are activating together. ://

look >> https://i.hizliresim.com/OoqGrA.png

Comment: Hmmm... I cannot open the page you posted a link for :/

Comment: how can i prevent this situation. it is redirected to a page I created with mvc. so the entire page reloading ://

Comment: *** I click on the link comes twice to the same block of code.